# Redux Form validation symbol does not render in browser?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

If you go to this website https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/, it shows that if the field is empty, this error message saying "Required" with an exclamation symbol shows up: 
[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRX6v.png)

This is the field code in my .tsx file:

```
<Field component={renderField} type="text" id="jobid" name="jobids"
    placeholder="enter id"
    validate={[FormValidation.required, FormValidation.jobids]}/>
```

These are the relevant export functions in my .ts file:

```
export class FormValidation {
        public static required = (value: string) => value ? undefined : 'Required';
}
```

For my project, however, an error square shows up instead of the exclamation symbol. I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. This happens on my computer and some colleague's computers, and we all use Mac OS. However, for one of my colleagues, the exclamation symbol renders correctly, and he uses Windows. Any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question with any relevant code tasked to your issue?

Comment: @ellitt I just updated it.

Comment: Does it render differently if you use different browsers?

Comment: Is that colleague using a different OS or something that would make the environment it's running on different from what you're using?

Comment: @ellitt I updated my post to address all of your questions

Comment: Do you see an error that looks like this in your browser console? `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED 
  https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: No, no such error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like FontAwesome isn't loaded and so the icon doesn't appear since it doesn't know how to render that glyph.

As far as I can tell, FontAwesome isn't a dependency for redux form, so you'll have to try including it manually somewhere in your project like index.html with something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

It works on the Redux Form docs site because they've included a link in the head tag of the document that loads font awesome from the same CDN in that snippet above.

As for why it shows up on your colleague's windows machine, I'm really not sure. I suppose if he has installed FontAwesome as a font locally that it might use that and be able to render the glyph correctly.

Comment: Glad to help! If that fixed the problem please accept this answer so that it might help someone else in the future.